# Villagers staring in the same spot and not breeding when given food, why is that happening?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was able to breed with two villagers before and it was all going fine. However, now they do not want to breed at all and just stare into the floor at a specific spot instead (both of them). What is causing this, or is this just a bug?

Answer (score -2):

This is not how you're supposed to breed villagers. You have to build a structure around them, some sort of wooden box that has to be pretty big and it should have doors everywhere inside of it. Then, push the two villagers inside, then give them some potatoes or carrots, just to make sure they are willing to mate, or trade with them like 5 times, then leave them there for a while and they will mate. If you came back to check and if they didn't mate, just give them more carrots and potatoes or trade several more times with them.

Comment: The door trick no longer works as of 1.14